# What are the options to make csh behave more Windows-like?

Tags: windows, bash, putty, csh

I'm using `csh` via PuTTY from a Windows PC and since I'm used to having the `HOME` button just place the cursor at the beginning of the string (instead of inserting `~`) or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd> place the cursor at the start/end of another word, I'd like to have that kind of navigation in the shell. What are the options for doing that?
I guess PuTTY just passes my commands to the shell and to do that kind of things I'd have to change its properties, but perhaps I could just tell PuTTY to substitute stuff for me or maybe use another client?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you using bash or csh? They are two different shells.

Comment: @AndrejaKo, in this situation csh, but it's not that I don't want that behavior in other shells I use

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's much you can do about csh other than run it using [`rlwrap`](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/uck/rlwrap/).

However, for tcsh and Bash, it's easy.

Here's an example for tcsh:

```
bindkey ^[OC forward-word
```

and for Bash:

```
bind '"\eOC": forward-word'
```

If you put this line in your `~/.inputrc` it will affect Bash, `rlwrap` and other readline-based programs:

```
"\eOC": forward-word
```

The character sequence you use will depend on what the terminal is emitting. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> then the key you're interested in, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> for example, and it will show you the sequence the key outputs. You'll see something like:

```
^[OC
```

which represents Escape-O-C. The Ctrl-[ is output as one character representing Escape, but you would type a carat then a left square bracket or a backslash and an "e".

You can list the bindings in tcsh using `bindkey` or in Bash using ``bind -p`.

Answer (score 0):

In PuTTY, have a look at the Keyboard options under the Terminal options.  I know you can fix the Home/End characters in they keyboard options, however I don't think there is anything you can do from PuTTY to get the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> to work, that would probably have to be a feature of your shell.